# Когда будет вызван Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net

Когда будет вызван Response.Dispose()?

```
 static public void Start()
    {
        var test = GetStream("http://site.ru/file1.dll");
        test.Dispose();
    }
    public static Stream GetStream(string Url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
        var str = Response.GetResponseStream();
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Кем он должен быть вызван?

Comment: Сборщиком мусора. Не понимаю когда ресурсы занятые response будут освобождены.

Comment: Никогда, вы не вызываете `Dispose()` явно и не используете директиву `using`. А еще вы используете устаревший `HttpWebRequest`. Используйте `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` вместо него.

Comment: [Необходимо вызвать метод Stream.Close или HttpWebResponse.Close, чтобы закрыть ответ и освободить подключение для повторного использования.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse?view=netframework-4.8). То есть не факт, что сборщик этот метод вообще вызовет, но если и вызовет, в тогда, когда ему захочется.